# Template property is invalid when trying to promote group to team

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently playing around with the Microsoft graph api, I have created a very simple react based SAP for trying out the api calls using the graph SDK. I have managed to create user groups successfully but I'm having troubles with promoting a group to team. The code that I use to try to call the API is as follows:

```
    const client = getAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);
    const request = {
      "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')",
      "group@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups('groupID')"
    }
    const team = await client
    .api('/teams')
    .post(request);
```

GroupID is a hardcoded string for the group I'm trying to promote.

When I call this code I simply receives an error message and its body property reads

`"{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Invalid bind property name template in request.","innerError":{"request-id":"68f35b65-175c-40f6-a241-b4774e305bcd","date":"2020-05-07T14:28:34"}}"`

I'm guessing that there is a problem with the template@odata.bind and maybe that I should call a different URL but in all examples that I have come across they use this one.

Is there something very obvious that I have missed or misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like since I was calling a beta endpoint with when I called the templates, I had to add a beta version flag.

```
const team = await client
    .api('/teams')
    .version('beta')
    .post(request);
```

This solved the issue